# How to count the highest value in every column in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I play games with my friends and I created a spreadsheet to record results. I am trying to create a formula which count how many times a person won.

To summarize, here is how the layout of the table formed:

column D6:D14 - how many rounds won (which is empty now)

From Column G6:ZZ14 - the records

For example

```
       D   G   H   I ...
--------------------
6  |     200 350 250 ...
7  |     340 400 300 ...
8  |     350 300 340 ...
9  |     450 250 500 ... 
10 |     500 200 300 ...
11 |     200 150 400 ...
...
```

So I tried to create a formula to count every win, there is:

`=SUM(SUM(IF(MAX($G$6:$G$11)=G6;1;0));SUM(IF(MAX($H$6:$H$11)=H6;1;0)))`

It adds 1 to the value if value (G6) is the highest value of that column ```MAX($G$6:$G$11), otherwise it adds 0. I used percent sign to copy down to D7:D14

It would not useful, because I have to write every column to the formula (in the example it works for column G and H but it last up to ZZ).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SUBTOTAL and OFFSET to return the max from each column, then Use SUMPRODUCT to count the matches:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($G$6,0,COLUMN($G$6:$I$11)-MIN(COLUMN($G$6:$I$11)),ROWS($G$6:$I$11),1))=G6:I6))
```

Depending on one's version this formula may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If you want to preset the range to a large range then use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($G$6,0,COLUMN($G$6:$ZZ$14)-MIN(COLUMN($G$6:$ZZ$14)),ROWS($G$6:$ZZ$14),1))=G6:ZZ6)*(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($G$6,0,COLUMN($G$6:$ZZ$14)-MIN(COLUMN($G$6:$ZZ$14)),ROWS($G$6:$ZZ$14),1))<>0))
```

Adding a condition to ignore the columns that do not have numbers, yet.

[image: ![enter image description here]

One thing to note, this formula is volatile and will recalc anytime something in Excel is changed and too large a range will slow down the responsiveness of Excel.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm!